# Cannot Change to a specific scene in Unity after building it to mobile device

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I'm using Application.load() to change scenes and it works perfectly in Unity. When I built it to a mobile platform and tested it, only in that one scene I can't change to a specific scene.

For example, gameplayScene, levelSelectionScene, mainMenu. I'm able to change scene from mainMenu to levelSelectionScene and then to gameplayScene. For unknown reason, I'm unable to go back to levelSelectionScene from gameplayScene while I can change scene to mainMenu from gameplayScene.
Below is the sample code from button that goes to levelSelectionScene from gameplayScene

```
    private void OnClick ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("clicked");

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SanguineDifficultyAchieved") == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Entering Difficulty");
            m_Owner.SetActive ();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Exiting");
            State.Current = State.NotInGame;
            Application.LoadLevel(scene.name);
        }
        m_Owner.close ();
```

I don't understand why it works on Unity debugger but then it doesn't work on mobile platforms.

## Update 1

I tried to use numbers instead of strings it worked well. But I still don't understand the reason why.

Comment: Did you add all scenes in the "Build Settings" dialog?

Comment: Yeah i added all of the scenes that i needed into build settings. Btw, from mainMenu i can change scene into levelSelectionScene. However from gameplay, i can't change scene into levelSelectionScene while i can change scene to mainMenu.

Comment: Do you get any runtime errors?

Comment: Nope no runtime errors. It worked when i use numbers though instead of the scene name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer. It seems that the scenes collided with each other because I use scenes from Asset Bundle and the added scenes from build settings. That is why the when i use Application.Load(int number) works because i only access the scene from build settings.